# Override or change executor configuration in spring

Tags: spring

I found the following definition

```
  <task:executor id="calculactionExecutor"
                 pool-size="${calculactionExecutor.poolSize}"
                 queue-capacity="${calculactionExecutor.queueCapacity}"
                 rejection-policy="ABORT"/>
```

which is great, it allows to change the settings by properties. I want to change the rejection-policy, is this possible by somehow extending or overriding the definition?

Comment: You want a new behavior when rejecting tasks or a new filter for rejecting tasks ?

Comment: `rejection-policy` is an enum, so you can only use what's available in there.